# Error 1332 while changing folder permissions with cacls

Tags: windows-10, user-permissions, uac

I want to change the user permissions of the folder `C:\Program Files\MyProgram` so that every user is allowed to write to that folder.

I am able to set the corresponding user rights manually within the windows explorer (no problem).
Because I have many computers I need to do that by a script.

`runas /user:Administrator "cacls \"C:\Program Files\MyProgram\" /T /E /G Users:F"`
did not work. It tells me that it is trying to run cacls as user Administrator, but I don't get any output message.

`psexec -u Administrator -p MyAdminPassword cacls "C:\Program Files\MyProgram" /T /E /G Users:F`
tells me `cacls exited with error code 1332`
For this code I found in the internet the error message `No mapping between account names and security IDs was done`, but I did not find any solution which worked.

UAC is disabled (I don't get any message. Before I also tried to put it on.)

**How can I give my user / all users write access to the folder `C:\Program Files\MyProgram`?**

Answer (score 0):

I would use `icacls` for this since `cacls` is now depreceated (Run it inside an elevated command prompt or `runas`):

```
takeown /f "C:\Program Files\My Program"
icacls "C:\Program Files\My Program" /grant Users:F
```